# Solve $I(\alpha)=\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}\frac{dx}{(x^\alpha+1)(1+x^2)}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Solve $$I(\alpha)=\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}\frac{dx}{(x^\alpha+1)(1+x^2)}.$$ Where $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $n \in \Bbb{R}.$

I would like to know how to solve this definite integral. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include what you have tried thus far and your thoughts about the problem.

Comment: Let $x=\tan t$ and then $\tan t=\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$. I think the answer will be  $\dfrac12$.

Comment: $x\to\frac{1}{x}$ and add the original integral with the transformed integral you end up with $$\int_{1/n}^n\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$ Which is strange given that it is independent of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitution $x\rightarrow 1/x$ makes that 
$$I(\alpha)=\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}\frac{x^\alpha\,dx}{(x^\alpha+1)(1+x^2)},$$ adding both equations gives 
$$2\,I(\alpha)=\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan n-\arctan\frac1n=2\arctan n- \frac{\pi}2,$$
i.e. $$I(\alpha)=\arctan n- \frac{\pi}4.$$

Comment: What the heck just happened?

Comment: @Ravi ? I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to how much the substitution simplifies the integral? If so, this is a pretty standard technique.

Comment: @Ravi It's not so rare, actually, though it happens more often with integrals from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and the easier substitution $x\rightarrow -x$. It's symmetrization, essentially. But this substitution is not infrequent, either, especially with rational functions. It's useful to have that in mind.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That was just me being surprised at how elegant the solution was.

Comment: @Ravi For more similar integrals, you might enjoy seeing [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/11779/evaluating-integrals-geometrically-without-using-the-fundamental-theorem-of-cal/12167#12167).

Comment: Please note: this is not mathematics, such questions are off topic and get closed to hell.

Comment: @ProfessorVector What is the "this" in your comment "this is not mathematics."

Comment: @Mark Viola "This question appears to be off-topic"

Comment: @ProfessorVector It is "off topic," but not because "it is not mathematics."  It is "off topic" because the question lacks context.  Clearly evaluation of an integral is mathematical.

Comment: @Mark Viola Please, be serious! That "rule" of "lacks context" is enforced in such an arbitrary form and so rarely that the _real_ reason is definitely something else. We won't ever know what that is (and I think we don't really want to, it's probably very ugly, or very stupid - it would have been done more openly, otherwise). And now, get my comment deleted, please, and I'll know I've hit home.